# Stored Procedure accept optional value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following code -

I am trying to create a procedure which takes in the products and an OPTIONAL start data and OPTIONAL end date. At the moment these dates cannot be left out

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.usp_Order') IS NOT NULL
        DROP PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Order
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Order
    AS
    SELECT
            o.OrderId
            o.product
            d.date

    FROM Order o

    INNER JOIN Dates d 

    ON o.orderid=d.dateid 

    WHERE "DATE" BETWEEN '09/16/2008' and '09/21/2016' 

    GO

        execute usp_Order
```

I have tried specifying @"date" date = null, and @"date" IS NULL in the where clause but doesnt work.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: What should happen if one of the dates is left out? Do you want to get all the records after/before the other date then? If both are left out, do you want to get all the records?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for optional parameters builds on the syntax for parameters in general.  Your stored procedure has no parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Order (
    @start_date date = NULL,
    @end_date date = NULL
AS
    SELECT o.OrderId o.product,  d.date
    FROM Order o INNER JOIN
         Dates d 
         ON o.orderid = d.dateid 
    WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN @start_date and @end_date
GO
```

As a note:  it looks like this stored procedure would make more sense as a table valued function, but that is another matter.  Also, you probably want to do something more intelligent with the default values than returning no rows; however, you don't specify what you want the defaults to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Order
(
    @Startdate date = null,
    @Enddate   date = null
)
AS
begin   
   SELECT
           o.OrderId
           o.product
           d.date

   FROM Order o

   INNER JOIN Dates d 

   ON o.orderid=d.dateid 

   WHERE    ([DATE] >= @Startdate  or @Startdate is null) 
        and ([DATE] <= @Enddate  or @Enddate is null) 
end
GO
```

Comment: you also need to specify a NULL default value for the date parameters so that they are optional.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid unexpected results from comparing dates to NULL, specify From date and To Date as minimum and maximum values of [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Order (
    @FromDate Datetime = '1753-01-01' -- January 1, 1753
    @ToDate Datetime = '9999-12-31' -- December 31, 9999
)
AS
SELECT
        o.OrderId
        o.product
        d.[date]

FROM Order o

INNER JOIN Dates d 

ON o.orderid=d.dateid 

WHERE d.[date] BETWEEN @FromDate and @ToDate

GO
```

Comment: Nahhh. Don't do that. Instead set the parameters to `null` by default and then compare like `WHERE d.[Date] >= ISNULL(@FromDate, d.[Date] AND d.[Date] <= ISNULL(@ToDate, d.[Date])`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Why? what's the benefit of using ISNULL function instead of hard coded min and max values? if anything, hard coded values should run faster.

Comment: A database listing all religious prophets would have some trouble with Jesus in your case... Also `null` is the definition of `not specified`, so if you don't want to specify something, `null` is the way to go. Everything else is rather unintuitive. But maybe that's just me...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar a database like that will not use datetime in the first place, but datetime2 or date. still I see no benefit in using ISNULL over max/min values. However, I will accept your claim about the definision of null.

Answer (score 0):

Declare Date1 Date2 like

```
    @Date1 date = NULL,
    @Date2 date = NULL
```

SELECT
            o.OrderId
            o.product
            d.date

```
FROM Order o

INNER JOIN Dates d 

ON o.orderid=d.dateid 

WHERE "DATE" BETWEEN @Date1 and @Date2
```

Comment: *and* make sure to modify the query ... how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account the case where one or both dates are `null`. As you have not specified whether you want to get all the records or no record then, I'll go with "get all the records":

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Order (
    @start_date date = NULL,
    @end_date date = NULL
AS
    SELECT o.OrderId o.product,  d.date
    FROM Order o INNER JOIN
         Dates d 
         ON o.orderid = d.dateid 
    WHERE 
        d.date BETWEEN ISNULL(@start_Date, d.date) AND ISNULL(@end_Date, d.date)
```